# How to concatenate the format string?

Tags: c++, formatting, fmt

I would like to concatenate two strings and use them as the format string for the `fmt` library.
One of the obvious choices is to simply concatenate them as regular strings and then pass them into the library:

```
template<typename... Args>
inline void catfmt(std::string a, std::string b, const Args &... args) {
    std::string c = a+b;
    fmt::print(c, args...);
}
```

However, `c` is going to be discarded. So maybe fmt provides a way for it to be skipped altogether? Is there a way to emplace a string into the message and tell the library that it too should be parsed? Something like:

```
template<typename... Args>
inline void catfmt(std::string a, std::string b, const Args &... args) {
    fmt::print("{:sf}{:sf}", a, b, args...);
}
```

Where `{:sf}` woud mean: emplace a string and use it as format.

Comment: I wonder why you need this. Why two format string and common list arguments to format? For a moment I thought `fmt::memory_buffer` should address your issue, but common use of arguments spoils this approach. Did you earlier joined arguments too?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to emplace a string into the message and tell the library that it too should be parsed?

There is no such way. You'll have to concatenate it using `operator+`, a nested call to format

```
fmt::print(fmt::runtime(fmt::format("{}{}", a, b)), args...);
```

or some other method.